# Поумолчанию задать radiobutton

Tags: html, javascript

Есть кнопка выбора, в зависимости от выбранного числа она либо display block либо none. Эта кнопка уходит в фильтр со значением либо true либо false (1 или 0). Поскольку когда radiobutton принимает значение display none, то человеку не выбрать ни одну кнопку, и в фильтр уходить пустое значени, в следствии чего он перестаёт работать, можно ли по умолчанию установить эту кнопку на какое то значение на случай display none?

```
# сама кнопка

Возможность выжить<br>
    Да<input type='radio' name='val4' value='1' /><br>
    Нет<input type='radio' name='val4' value='0' /><br />

# то что приходит в фильтр

 {name:"значение",val1:31,val2:'',val3:true,val4:true,val5:false,},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type='radio' name='val3' checked value='0' />
```

таким образом это можно обойти